# Getting "Missing credentials in config" in AWS and Ionic

Tags: amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, aws-sdk

I am currently having a big problem with my application which uses AWS as backend. When I test the application I get an error for the first time the application is installed on the phone or when I serve it on browser. For the first time after the login immediately I have to load data of the user from the DynamoDB but I get this error

> POST https://cognito-identity.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ 400 ()
>       Error: Missing credentials in config

So I have consoled the Credentials I found that its all set to null. After the first refresh of the page (close an open the app on phone). I noticed that the credentials are no longer empty but still the DynamoDb query not processing.

And for the third refresh everything back to work as wanted. This made the user experience of my application so bad, so I have to find a solution.

Here is my Login function

```
 login(username, password) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let user = this.cognito.makeUser(username);
      let authDetails = this.cognito.makeAuthDetails(username, password);

      user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
        'onSuccess': (result:any) => {

          var logins = {};
          var loginKey = 'cognito-idp.' +
                          aws_cognito_region +
                          '.amazonaws.com/' +
                          aws_user_pools_id;
          logins[loginKey] = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

          AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
           'IdentityPoolId': aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
           'Logins': logins
          });



          AWS.config.credentials.get((err) => {
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            }

            this.isAuthenticated().then(() => {
              resolve();
            }).catch((err) => {
              console.log('auth session failed');
            });
          });

        },

        'onFailure': (err:any) => {

          console.log('authentication failed');
          reject(err);

        },
        newPasswordRequired: (userAttributes, Password) => {
          // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
          // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
          // authentication.
          var newPassword;
          console.log(newPassword);
          delete userAttributes.email_verified;
          delete userAttributes.phone_number_verified;

          let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ChangePasswordPage );
          addModal.onDidDismiss(data => {

            newPassword = data;
            user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(newPassword, userAttributes, {
              onSuccess: (result:any) => {
                  var logins = {};
                  var loginKey = 'cognito-idp.' +
                                  aws_cognito_region +
                                  '.amazonaws.com/' +
                                  aws_user_pools_id;
                   logins[loginKey] = result.getIdToken().getJwtToken();

                   AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
                   'IdentityPoolId': aws_cognito_identity_pool_id,
                   'Logins': logins
                  });

                   AWS.config.credentials.get((err) => {
                    if (err) {
                      return reject(err);
                    }


                    });
                  this.isAuthenticated().then(() => { 
                    resolve();
                  }).catch((err) => {
                    console.log('auth session failed');
                  });


              },
              authSuccess: function (result){

                console.log('In the AuthSuccess.');

              },
              onFailure: function(err) {
                console.log('In the Error '+err);

              }
            }); 

             console.log(newPassword);

          })
          addModal.present();
          console.log(newPassword);

      }
      });
    });
  }
```

And here is my dynamoDb function :

```
refreshTasks() {

  console.log( AWS.config.credentials);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  var d = new Date();
  var s=  [this.pad(d.getDate()), this.pad(d.getMonth()+1), d.getFullYear()].join('/');
    console.log(s);


  const params = {
    'TableName': this.dailyTable,

    'KeyConditionExpression':
     "#userId = :userId AND d = :day",
    'ExpressionAttributeNames': {
       '#userId': 'userId'
  },
    'ExpressionAttributeValues': {
       ':userId': AWS.config.credentials.identityId,
       ':day':s.toString()
     },
    'ScanIndexForward': false
  };

  this.db.getDocumentClient().query(params).promise().then((data) => {
    console.log("data loaded");

    console.log(data);
    resolve(data);

  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
  });
}
```

Comment: May be related: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=176098

Comment: Already spent a week trying the existing solutions . but no hope.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: How long you've spent on the problem, or general statements of woe, are not useful to readers, and they may be understood as a form of pleading, which in turn may attract downvotes. I recommend sticking to the facts when asking questions, and then of course continuing to research the issue while waiting for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by allowing anonym access to the mobile hub project . As the credentials lazy load . And query the table with the user ID until the credentials are ready . This is a temporary   solution for who has the same problem .